# Removing Google Map markers from Map was working, now its not

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

As i am working on object oriented javascript, i have created one map object and as i need to maintain the all previous routes and markers i am not creating new Map object. My code is as follows

```
function map() {

    this.defaultMapOption   =    {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        zoom : 1,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map    =   null;

    this.marker =   [];

    this.directionsDisplay = null;
}

map.prototype.init = function() {


    this.map    =   new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), this.defaultMapOption);

    var map1    =   this.map;
    var marker1 =   this.marker;

    var count   =   0;

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {

        count++;

        $(".tabNavigation li").find("a[href=markers]").trigger('click');

        if ( marker1[count] ) {
            marker1[count].setPosition(event.latLng);
        }
        else
        {
            marker1[count] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latLng,
                map: map1,
                draggable : true
            });

            //by clicking double click on marker, marker must be removed.
            google.maps.event.addListener(map.marker[count], "dblclick", function() {

                console.log(map.marker);

                map.marker[count].setMap(null);//this was working previously
                map.marker[count].setVisible(false);//added this today

                $("#markers ul li[rel='"+count+"']").remove();

            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1[count], "dragend", function(innerEvent) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': innerEvent.latLng}, function(results, status) {

                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.addMarkerData(results, count);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                    }
                });
            }); 

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': event.latLng}, function(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    map.addMarkerData(results, count);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Only above code works for only one marker. Means first time marker get removed on double click. After that it wont work.

Any ideas that why its stopped working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count value is incrementing with new markers and in `addListener(map.marker[count],...)` , count will contain the latest value. So only that marker will be deleted.

So you should be decrementing the `count` value at the end in the addListener function.

Comment: ups.. you are right.. My stupidity... needs to be done in different way.. thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're adding marker[1] but then you try to remove marker[0]. Move your `count++;` from the beginning to the end of the function.

Comment: nope.. I already bind the `double click` event for each of them. Its not the problem.

Comment: The answer from Cdeez is exactly the same as I said.

Comment: might be, but it was easy for me to understood the @Cdeez answer then yours.. but yet your answer mean that `marker` array must start from 0, and according to me that was not problem. Problem was the bind function. Whereas @Cdeez said clearly that because of the `count` containing the latest value will be deleted..

Comment: Every array starts from index 0 in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, it does, but you're obviously not interested in my answers. I'm sorry I tried to help you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16806/discussion-between-kuku-and-marcelo)